# Cura code for run-out sensor Ender 3 V2

Tags: creality-ender-3

New to the 3D printing world. I'm in need of some advice.  Is it possible to add code to Cura for the run-out sensor? I've had no luck narrowing the commands or anything that speaks to it. I was able to get the BLTouch working correctly.

Comment: I just recently started 3D printing, but I believe that the run-out sensor is tied to the firmware of the printer. Maybe someone more experienced can give some additional details.

Comment: I guess I need to go ahead and try to compile the firmware needed. Thanks for the reply.